# Are comic book cover questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question regarding a stamp symbol I've noticed on several marvel comics of mine.  It's likely not in-universe related and more of a promotional thing but I'd like to know what it is.

Is it acceptable to ask a question about this? Or are in-universe questions only allowed?

Answer (score 8):

From the [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq):

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> …
>
> - Historical or societal context of a work

As long as the comics are speculative fiction, the question should be on-topic.